# Implementation forested glass effect in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

how do you implemente forsted glass effect on an item when it's focus or had been selected? Consider an requirement,I have an item contain icon and text, I want to the item  been forest glass focused, how to implement this using android UI framework, does it need  custom the layout  and draw on it?

Comment: Do you mean frosted glass effect like iOS7?

Comment: no, when the item get focus,a forested glass border around it, the item get bigger and seems rise up a little, just  like a magnifier glass on it.